# Slicing pandas dataframe at location of a character

Tags: python, pandas

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'Email': ['xx@hotmail.com', 'yy@gmail.com', 'zz@aol.com'], 
                       'B':[4, 5, 6]}).
```

I want to get the rows containing the substring '@domain.com' in column 'Email'.

I have tried splicing a few different ways and couldn't find a previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `testdf['domain'] = '@' + testdf.Email.str.partition('@')[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.str.split`:

```
testdf.Email.str.split('@').str[1]
```

Output:

```
0    hotmail.com
1      gmail.com
2        aol.com
Name: Email, dtype: object
```

With '@':

```
'@' + testdf.Email.str.split('@').str[1]
```

OUtput:

```
0    @hotmail.com
1      @gmail.com
2        @aol.com
Name: Email, dtype: object
```